# Open graph action submission

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible that although I haven't submitted yet my open graph's actions to Facebook, the actions are being seen by users which are not developers/administrators?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is in sandbox mode it can only seen by developers,tester etc...

But if sandbox mode disabled it can be seen by anybody who knows the url. The only difference is if your open graph objects and actions aren't submitted. They can't use them it will give error.

Comment: I don't know the error exactly but it will look like this; {"message":"(#100) The Action Type video:Watch is not approved, so app 366168323431073 can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User 100001205364418 is not one of those roles.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}

Comment: It's not in sandbox. What do you mean by "They can't use them"? the application is posting action on their behalf so where this error is occurring?

Comment: But we can see posts from people which aren't developer..so there's not such error for them

Comment: You can't see someone's actions in your site because Open Graph actions only posted in timeline of user who uses application. I don't know what you saw? If you mean comments on social plugins or something like that they aren't Open graph objects and actions